# How to execute action whenever MEF instantiates (exports) new object?

Tags: c#, mef, modularity

I'm building a modular app with MEF, and been trying to come up with smart ideas how handle saving/loading states.
In certain situations (eg when user clicks "save"), my shell will have to trigger some sort of save/load action, which plugins may want to be aware of to be able to save and load their own states.

There are a lot of possible ways of course including events and a global message bus, however my preferred idea at the moment is based on two interfaces:

```
public interface ISaveAndLoadState
{
    void SaveState(XmlWriter writer);
    void LoadState(XmlReader reader);
}

public interface IStateManager
{
    void Register(ISaveAndLoadState item);

    void Save(Stream stream);
    void Load(Stream stream);
}
```

Then plugins - their modules, view models or anything - could do the following:

```
[Export]
public class iAmAPluginViewModelOrModule : ISaveAndLoadState
{
      [ImportingConstructor]
  public iAmAPluginViewModelOrModule(IStateManager m)
  {
        m.Register(this);
  }

  public void SaveState(XmlWriter writer) { ..... }
  public void LoadState(XmlReader reader) { ..... }

}
```

This should work reasonably well. However, I think it'd be even nicer if classes that implement ISaveAndLoadState wouldn't have to call IStateManager.Register() explicitly - but rather that when MEFs instantiates a class implementing ISaveAndLoadState, it automatically registers it with the IStateManager.

So basically, I'd need an "event" triggering whenever MEF instantiates any new object, and then do something like

```
public void OnMefHasCreatedInstance(object instance)
{
  var _inst = instance as ISaveAndLoadState;

 if(_inst != null)
   Container.GetExportedValue<IStateManager>().Register(_inst);
}
```

Is that possible at all? Is there any way to listen to / be informed to when MEF has created a new instsance?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite answering your question but it is possibly another solution for you.

If you export each class with the `ISaveAndLoadState` interface, then you can use an `ImportMany` within your `StateManager`

```
[Export(typeof(ISaveAndLoadState))]
public class iAmAPluginViewModelOrModule : ISaveAndLoadState

public class StateManager : IStateManager
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(ISaveAndLoadState))]
    private List<ISaveAndLoadState> _saveAndLoadStates;
}
```

Then `_saveAndLoadStates` should be populated with all of your objects and you can just loop through them in the `StateManager` `Load` and `Save` methods.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Not all classes using this will be composed, but more importantly - I'd prefer to have the exports instantiated when needed by the consumers, not right away when importing into the state manager (and if I import them as Lazy<ISaveAndLoadState>, I might register them too late). I now went with using an InterceptingCatalog from MefContrib and register an IExportedValueInterceptor to register in my state manager after instantiation; almost seems like a bit overkill, but so far this works rather nicely.